# Command not found in zsh, but found in bash

Tags: bash, zsh, path, home, tilde

I'm using `zsh` on ubuntu and I created a symlink for `bat` as so:

`ln -s /usr/bin/batcat /home/user_name/.local/bin/bat`

hitting `ls -l` from `~/.local/bin` shows:

`lrwxrwxrwx 1 tux tux       15 May 19 13:47 bat -> /usr/bin/batcat`

Now from any directory(even in `~/.local/bin`),

If I run `bat`, I get `command not found: bat`. Also running `~/.local/bin` doesn't work. However, running `./bat`(from `~/.local/bin`) does work. Running `batcat` also works.

`echo $PATH` shows that `~/.local/bin` is in the path

What could be going wrong here? no symlink works, `bat` is just an example

P.S. In bash, things are working as expected

Comment: Does `echo $PATH` list `~/.local/bin` with a tilde, or does it list `/home/user_name/.local/bin`? It needs to have the full path. Bash works with `~`, but that isn't really helpful because programs started by bash don't recognize the `~`. Zsh doesn't have this misfeature.

Comment: It has a tilde. Works perfectly after adding the full path instead of the tilde. Thanks!

Comment: Although replacing tilde with full path worked for me but in vim, fzf `BLines` somehow still says `bat` error, file or directory not found

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If your `PATH` actually contains `~/.local/bin` with the literal tilde character: that won't work. The tilde needs to be expanded to your home directory.

For example, any of these lines are correct in zsh, bash or any other sh-like shell:

```
PATH=~/.local/bin:$PATH
PATH=$PATH:~/.local/bin
PATH=~/.local/bin:"$PATH"
PATH="$PATH":~/.local/bin
export PATH="$HOME/.local/bin:$PATH"
export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.local/bin"
```

They work because `~` is expanded to the home directory when it's at the beginning of a word, immediately after the equal sign in an assignment, or immediately after a `:` in the right-hand side of an assignment (the purpose of this last rule is precisely for the convenience of setting `PATH`).

But a line like `PATH="~/.local/bin:$PATH"` won't work, because `~` is not expanded in double quotes, so the value of `PATH` ends up containing the literal character `~`. This `PATH` references a directory called `~` in the current directory, not your home directory.

Bash¹ has a feature in which `~` is interpreted as the home directory at the start of path entries. So `PATH="~/.local/bin:$PATH"` does partially work in bash. However, it only works when you run a program from bash directly, not when programs other than bash themselves start programs. So even if you use bash, don't put a literal `~` in the path, make sure it's expanded or use `$HOME` instead.

---

<sup>When not in POSIX mode like when running as `sh`, as that feature breaks POSIX compliance as a `PATH='~'` is meant to look for commands in the literal `~` subdirectory of the current working directory.</sup>